# Problema con secuencias de escape

Tags: c#, devexpress

El siguiente método corresponde al evento EditValueChanged de un combobox que tiene almacenados filtros de un gridview. Utilizo este evento para que al seleccionar el índice, pueda poder obtener el "where" que corresponde a la consulta SQL que tiene almacenada dicho filtro.

```
private void LookUpCuentas_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LookUpCuentas.ItemIndex == 0)
        {
            gridView2.ClearColumnsFilter();
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream tempMem = new MemoryStream((LookUpCuentas.GetSelectedDataRow() as Filtro).FiltroFile);
            Extensions.RestoreLayoutFromXmlEx(gridView2, provider, tempMem);

            DataView dv = new DataView();
            CriteriaOperator op = gridView2.ActiveFilterCriteria;
            string filterString = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(op);
            dv.RowFilter = filterString;
            MessageBox.Show(dv.RowFilter);
        }
        gridCuentas.Focus();
    }
```

En el método creo un `DataView (dv)` y un `CriteriaOperator` (op) que almacena el filtro que selecciono del combo (por ejemplo selecciono el filtro Entre Rios, entonces op almacena: `Provincia.NombreProvincia = 'Entre Rios')`. Luego con `CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetMsSqlWhere(op)` obtengo el where del filtro y en filterString me queda almacenado `"(\"Provincia.NombreProvincia\" = N'ENTRE RIOS')"` que es lo que necesito para trabajarlo mas adelante. Pero acá es donde me arroja la excepción de sintaxis:

> Additional information: Cannot interpret token '"' at position 28.

Y en el detalle de la exepción  me indica que no interpreta \"

> {"Cannot interpret token '\"' at position 28."}

Intenté modificar la secuencia de escape con el siguiente código:

```
filterString.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Trim();
```

y con

```
filterString.Replace(@"""", @"\""").Trim();
```

pero el error sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: Esto puede ser `DevExpress`?

Comment: Si, es devexpress

Comment: Te estaba escribiendo una respuesta hasta que me di cuenta. De todas maneras, prueba a pasarle a `dv.RowFilter` lo que te devuelve el `CriteriaOperator `, o sea `Provincia.NombreProvincia = 'Entre Rios'`. Eso es lo que el dataview entiende

Comment: Si perdón, me olvidé de aclararlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la ayuda de @Pikoh pude solucionarlo, no hizo falta trabajar con las secuencias de escape, simplemente pasé el resultado de CriteriaOperator al dv.RowFilter. Entonces el método queda de la siguiente manera:

```
private void LookUpCuentas_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LookUpCuentas.ItemIndex == 0)
        {
            gridView2.ClearColumnsFilter();
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream tempMem = new MemoryStream((LookUpCuentas.GetSelectedDataRow() as Filtro).FiltroFile);
            Extensions.RestoreLayoutFromXmlEx(gridView2, provider, tempMem);

            DataView dv = new DataView();
            CriteriaOperator op = gridView2.ActiveFilterCriteria;
            dv.RowFilter = op.ToString();

        }
        gridCuentas.Focus();
    }
```